# Scheme Character Comparison

Tags: list, scheme, character

Let's say I have a list like this one:

```
(define test '(r x -))
```

I want to know how can I distinguish each of the values in the list, for exaple:

`(define (distinguish test) (equal? (car test) r))` -> Of course this returns error, but I would like it to return #t or something like that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you asking how to access the symbols `r`, `x` and `-`, as in `car`, `cadr` and `caddr`?

Comment: No, I'm asking how can I get 'true' for the operation (equal? (car test) r) As if it is comparing **r** with **r**, because it actually returns 'Error'

Comment: You should write: `(define (distinguish test) (equal? (car test) 'r))`.

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A symbol not quoted in code is **a variable**

```
(define r 'x)        ; define the variable r to be the symbol x
(eq? (car test) r)   ; ==> #f (compares the symbol r with symbol x)
(eq? (cadr test) r)  ; ==> #t (compares the symbol x with the symbol x)
(eq? (car test) 'r)  ; ==> #t (compares the symbol r with the symbol r)
```

Symbol in list comparison

```
(define test-list '(fi fa foo))
(define test-symbol 'fi)
(eq? (car test-list) test-symbol) ; ==> #t (compares fi with fi)
(eq? 'fi 'fi)                     ; ==> #t (compares fi with fi)
```

Character in String comparison (The question title is about character not symbol):

```
(define test-string "test")
(define test-char #\t)
(eqv? (string-ref test-string 0) test-char) ; ==> #t (compares #\t with #\t)
(eqv? #\t #\t)                              ; ==> #t (compares #\t with #\t)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is really helpful too.